# Update each element in linked list with the data of the previous element

Tags: linked-list

Given a one-way linked list, I want to update each element's value with the value of the previous node, for instance, if I have list 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> null, so after the run it'll be *new_value* -> 1 -> 2 -> null where *new_value* is given in each iteration.

What I've tried to do (pseudo-code) is:

```
list_head = head
for i = length-1 to 0:
    current = head
    do i times:
        prev_data = current.data
        current = current.next
    current.data = prev_data
```

It doesn't seem to work properly, though...what am I missing? is there another way to do it?

EDIT: assume that *new_value* is already assigned to head at this point

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the output?

Comment: It's part of a bigger project so the answer to that is a bit complicated :), but I don't see the desired results at the end...

Comment: The immediate issue I see is that you seem to always pointing `current` to `head` for the next iteration. That looks wrong to me. Do you have a reference to the `tail`?

Comment: No I don't since it's only one-way. Anyway I think that code is correct and my bug is in another place. Thanks anyway

Comment: I would request you to provide all relevant information in the future so that users don't waste their time helping you out. Have a good day :)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement list with arrays as well. Here is an implementation in javascript. Hope it helps.

```js
var array = [1,2,3]; // list with array
var newValue = 4;
function push(value){
 array.pop(); // to remove the last element
 array.unshift(value); // to add the new element
 console.log(array);
}
push(newValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not see a reason why you would need to use two loops - I suspect your issue has to do with the "do i times". Instead I would suggest to simply push the values through the list until the tail has been reached (and the last value is dropped). The following is an implementation of that idea using a very simple `Node` class:

```js
function Node(data,next=null) {
 this.data = data;
 this.next = next;
 this.toString = function() {
  if(this.next) return this.data + " -> " + this.next.toString();
  else return this.data + " -> null";
 }
}

var head = new Node(1,new Node(2,new Node(3)));
console.log(head.toString())

var new_value = 0;
var curr = head;
do{
 var old_value = curr.data;
 curr.data = new_value;
 new_value = old_value;
 curr = curr.next;
} while(curr)

console.log(head.toString());
```